# BAT中にPowerShellを用いて数値をカンマ付きの数字にしたい

Tags: powershell, batch-file

#### 目的

下記の通り、数字をカンマ付きにしたい。

**元の数値:**

```
123456789
```

**期待する結果:**

```
123,456,789
```

#### 試したこと

PowerShellでは以下のコードでカンマ付きに変換出来るので、

```
PowerShell '{0:#,#}' -f 123456789
>> 123,456,789
```

BATでこの様に記述してやったのですが、期待する結果になりません。
ご教授頂けると幸いです。

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=" %%A IN ('PowerShell '{0:#,#}' -f 123456789') DO (ECHO %%A)
>> 12345678 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この記事の後から付いた回答の応用で、PowerShellコマンドのパラメータを`"`で囲えば良いのでは？
[Return PowerShell Command result in batch file](https://superuser.com/q/1269124)

このようにすれば出来るでしょう。

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=" %%A IN ('PowerShell "'{0:#,#}' -f 123456789"') DO (ECHO %%A)
```

Comment: 確かに動作しました。お手数おかけしましたありがとうございます。